# MySQL Strict Standards Warning - Redefining Already Defined Constructor for Class

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I have an issue with my PHP script and cannot seem to get around it. I'm testing out a login/register mock site script and am getting the following error:

**Strict Standards: Redefining already defined constructor for class GoodGirls1Database in C:\vhosts\goodgirls1\core\database\db.php on line 25**

Here's the code for the `db.php` file:

```
<?php
// Our database class
if(!class_exists('GoodGirls1Database')){
class GoodGirls1Database {

    /**
     * Connects to the database server and selects a database
     *
     * PHP4 compatibility layer for calling the PHP5 constructor.
     *
     * @uses GoodGirls1Database::__construct()
     *
     */ 
    function GoodGirls1Database() {
        return $this->__construct();
    }

    /**
     * Connects to the database server and selects a database
     *
     * PHP5 style constructor for compatibility with PHP5. Does
     * the actual setting up of the connection to the database.
     *
     */
    function __construct() {
        $this->connect();
    }

    /**
     * Connect to and select database
     *
     * @uses the constants defined in config.php
     */ 
    function connect() {
        $link = mysqli_connect('localhost', DB_USER, DB_PASS);

        if (!$link) {
            die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
        }

        $db_selected = mysqli_select_db('DB_NAME', $link);

        if (!$db_selected) {
            die('Can\'t use ' . DB_NAME . ': ' . mysql_error());
        }
    }

    /**
     * Clean the array using mysql_real_escape_string
     *
     * Cleans an array by array mapping mysql_real_escape_string
     * onto every item in the array.
     *
     * @param array $array The array to be cleaned
     * @return array $array The cleaned array
     */
    function clean($array) {
        return array_map('mysql_real_escape_string', $array);
    }

    /**
     * Create a secure hash
     *
     * Creates a secure copy of the user password for storage
     * in the database.
     *
     * @param string $password The user's created password
     * @param string $nonce A user-specific NONCE
     * @return string $secureHash The hashed password
     */
    function hash_password($password, $nonce) {
      $secureHash = hash_hmac('sha512', $password . $nonce, SITE_KEY);

      return $secureHash;
    }

    /**
     * Insert data into the database
     *
     * Does the actual insertion of data into the database.
     *
     * @param resource $link The MySQL Resource link
     * @param string $table The name of the table to insert data into
     * @param array $fields An array of the fields to insert data into
     * @param array $values An array of the values to be inserted
     */
    function insert($link, $table, $fields, $values) {
        $fields = implode(", ", $fields);
        $values = implode("', '", $values);
        $sql="INSERT INTO $table (id, $fields) VALUES ('', '$values')";

        if (!mysql_query($sql)) {
            die('Error: ' . mysql_error());
        } else {
            return TRUE;
        }
    }

    /**
     * Select data from the database
     *
     * Grabs the requested data from the database.
     *
     * @param string $table The name of the table to select data from
     * @param string $columns The columns to return
     * @param array $where The field(s) to search a specific value for
     * @param array $equals The value being searched for
     */
    function select($sql) {
        $results = mysql_query($sql);

        return $results;
    }
}
}

//Instantiate our database class
$ggdb = new GoodGirls1Database;
?>
```

Of course I made a few subtle changes in the script, but I'm unfamiliar as this particular error. Also, my test database which was named `goodgirls_1`, was changed because I am also getting this error:

**Warning: mysqli_select_db() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli, string given in C:\vhosts\goodgirls1\core\database\db.php on line 41
Can't use goodgirls1:**  Yet I still get the error for `goodgirls1`.

And likewise, here's the code for a file, `config.php` relative to the `db.php` file:

```
<?php
/* Configuration Info
 * Enter your configuration information below.
 */

//Database Information

/* DB Name
 * Enter the name of your database below.
 */
define('DB_NAME', 'goodgirls1');

/* DB Username
 * Enter the username of the user with access to the database below.
 */
define('DB_USER', 'root');

/* DB Password
 * Enter the above user's password below.
 */
define('DB_PASS', 'TempPass4!');

//SALT Information

/* Site Key
 * Enter your site key below. Used by adding 8 random 16-character string values.     Recreated by DesignerMind.
 */
define('SITE_KEY', 'DFDfdd Jea*jdfv(087KlwacbMFd dfj()8&^(%)+-dfwqefd55d*fMhb!@$%&^%VQJsxGjOIdej#OT3EhCpxqC5Bu6KSOJM$$##VJV9jLF5uWiiFXm1G');                 

/* NONCE SALT
 * Enter your NONCE SALT below. Recreated by DesignerMind.
 */
define('NONCE_SALT', 'e^$#fdf)jdffdASQ2_)(eh2DfbOOX4*&F73ldggm8KZP35N48t3OVbTaoOpaOlLydef#_+kvusgNgafnuujTPdazfzqpDy');

/* AUTH SALT
 * Enter your AUTH SALT below. Recreated by DesignerMind.
 */
define('AUTH_SALT', '-=+fQ~223_ofydfdUm9SXCqWWvSDm6&^&k3iwMqPghWzTgqMSiy)(&*&RaAoM/**J343^((&!N_=dfdfOp4vH(gwL0fA75/vH04r2xjp7KH2ahNNc');
?>
```

Lastly, if needed, here's a `class.php` file which I use to instantiate my database:

```
<?php
// Our main class
if(!class_exists('GoodGirls1')){
class GoodGirls1 {

    function register($redirect) {
        global $ggdb;

        //Check to make sure the form submission is coming from our script
        //The full URL of our registration page
        $current = 'http://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];

        //The full URL of the page the form was submitted from
        $referrer = $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'];

        /*
         * Check to see if the $_POST array has date (i.e. our form was submitted) and if so,
         * process the form data.
         */
        if ( !empty ( $_POST ) ) {

            /* 
             * Here we actually run the check to see if the form was submitted from our
             * site. The registration from submits to itself; 
             * If the form submission didn't come from the register.php page on our server,
             * we don't allow the data through.
             */
            if ( $referrer == $current ) {

                //Require our database class
                require_once('../../db.php');

                //Set up the variables we'll need to pass to our insert method
                //This is the name of the table we want to insert data into
                $table = 'users';

                //These are the fields in that table that we want to insert data into
                $fields = array('username', 'password', 'first_name', 'last_name', 'email', 'user_registered');

                //These are the values from our registration form... cleaned using our clean method
                $values = $ggdb->clean($_POST);

                //Now, we're breaking apart our $_POST array, so we can storely our password securely
                $username = $_POST['username'];
                $userpass = $_POST['password'];
                $userfirst = $_POST['first_name'];
                $userlast = $_POST['last_name'];                    
                $useremail = $_POST['email'];
                $userreg = $_POST['date'];

                //We create a NONCE using the action, username, timestamp, and the NONCE SALT
                $nonce = md5('registration-' . $username . $userreg . NONCE_SALT);

                //We hash our password
                $userpass = $ggdb->hash_password($userpass, $nonce);

                //Recompile our $value array to insert into the database
                $values = array(
                            'username' => $username,
                            'password' => $userpass,
                            'first_name' => $userfirst,
                            'last_name' => $userlast,                               
                            'email' => $useremail,
                            'date' => $userreg
                        );

                //And, we insert our data
                $insert = $ggdb->insert($link, $table, $fields, $values);

                if ( $insert == TRUE ) {
                    $url = "http" . ((!empty($_SERVER['HTTPS'])) ? "s" : "") . "://".$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'].$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
                    $aredirect = str_replace('register.php', $redirect, $url);

                    header("Location: $redirect?reg=true");
                    exit;
                }
            } else {
                die('Your form submission did not come from the correct page. Please check with the site administrator.');
            }
        }
    }

    function login($redirect) {
        global $ggdb;

        if ( !empty ( $_POST ) ) {

            //Clean our form data
            $values = $ggdb->clean($_POST);

            //The username and password submitted by the user
            $subname = $values['username'];
            $subpass = $values['password'];

            //The name of the table we want to select data from
            $table = 'users';

            /*
             * Run our query to get all data from the users table where the user 
             * login matches the submitted login.
             */
            $sql = "SELECT * FROM $table WHERE user_login = '" . $subname . "'";
            $results = $ggdb->select($sql);

            //Kill the script if the submitted username doesn't exit
            if (!$results) {
                die('Sorry, that username does not exist!');
            }

            //Fetch our results into an associative array
            $results = mysql_fetch_assoc( $results );

            //The registration date of the stored matching user
            $storeg = $results['user_registered'];

            //The hashed password of the stored matching user
            $stopass = $results['password'];

            //Recreate our NONCE used at registration
            $nonce = md5('registration-' . $subname . $storeg . NONCE_SALT);

            //Rehash the submitted password to see if it matches the stored hash
            $subpass = $ggdb->hash_password($subpass, $nonce);

            //Check to see if the submitted password matches the stored password
            if ( $subpass == $stopass ) {

                //If there's a match, we rehash password to store in a cookie
                $authnonce = md5('cookie-' . $subname . $storeg . AUTH_SALT);
                $authID = $ggdb->hash_password($subpass, $authnonce);

                //Set our authorization cookie
                setcookie('goodgirls1logauth[user]', $subname, 0, '', '', '', true);
                setcookie('goodgirls1logauth[authID]', $authID, 0, '', '', '', true);

                //Build our redirect
                $url = "http" . ((!empty($_SERVER['HTTPS'])) ? "s" : "") . "://".$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'].$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
                $redirect = str_replace('login.php', $redirect, $url);

                //Redirect to the home page
                header("Location: $redirect");
                exit;   
            } else {
                return 'invalid';
            }
        } else {
            return 'empty';
        }
    }

    function logout() {
        //Expire our auth coookie to log the user out
        $idout = setcookie('goodgirls1logauth[authID]', '', -3600, '', '', '', true);
        $userout = setcookie('goodgirls1logauth[user]', '', -3600, '', '', '', true);

        if ( $idout == true && $userout == true ) {
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }

    function checkLogin() {
        global $ggdb;

        //Grab our authorization cookie array
        $cookie = $_COOKIE['goodgirls1logauth'];

        //Set our user and authID variables
        $user = $cookie['user'];
        $authID = $cookie['authID'];

        /*
         * If the cookie values are empty, we redirect to login right away;
         * otherwise, we run the login check.
         */
        if ( !empty ( $cookie ) ) {

            //Query the database for the selected user
            $table = 'users';
            $sql = "SELECT * FROM $table WHERE username = '" . $user . "'";
            $results = $ggdb->select($sql);

            //Kill the script if the submitted username doesn't exit
            if (!$results) {
                die('Sorry, that username does not exist!');
            }

            //Fetch our results into an associative array
            $results = mysql_fetch_assoc( $results );

            //The registration date of the stored matching user
            $storeg = $results['user_registered'];

            //The hashed password of the stored matching user
            $stopass = $results['password'];

            //Rehash password to see if it matches the value stored in the cookie
            $authnonce = md5('cookie-' . $user . $storeg . AUTH_SALT);
            $stopass = $ggdb->hash_password($stopass, $authnonce);

            if ( $stopass == $authID ) {
                $results = true;
            } else {
                $results = false;
            }
        } else {
            //Build our redirect
            $url = "http" . ((!empty($_SERVER['HTTPS'])) ? "s" : "") . "://".$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'].$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
            $redirect = str_replace('index.php', 'login.php', $url);

            //Redirect to the home page
            header("Location: $redirect?msg=login");
            exit;
        }

        return $results;
    }
}
}

//Instantiate our database class
$gg1 = new GoodGirls1;
?>
```

This is my first **major PHP script** that I've had to edit and break down, and would appreciate the knowledge as to why I'm running to in the snags I'm hitting with the Warnings. I know there are some `mysql` portions where there should be `mysqli`, but I'm trying to step my way through a section at a time on the errors. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***Strict Standards: Redefining already defined constructor for class GoodGirls1Database in C:\vhosts\goodgirls1\core\database\db.php on line 25***

This error is because you have declared class name as GoodGirls1Database and you have also implemented a method named GoodGirls1Database in that class. Try changing either the name of the method or the class name.

***Warning: mysqli_select_db() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli, string given in C:\vhosts\goodgirls1\core\database\db.php on line 41 Can't use goodgirls1:***

You are passing the wrong order of parameters in `mysqli_select_db()`. `$link` should be first parameter.

```
function connect() {
        $link = mysqli_connect('localhost', DB_USER, DB_PASS);

        if (!$link) {
            die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
        }

 This line  ---->     $db_selected = mysqli_select_db($link,'DB_NAME');

        if (!$db_selected) {
            die('Can\'t use ' . DB_NAME . ': ' . mysql_error());
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks, after some tweaking and adding to the parameters, it worked!

Comment: Glad I could be of some help :)